# Action bar, how to hide the actionbar if a certain tab is clicked (full screen for that tab click)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I was reading about the action bar in Android (how it has tabs). My question is, assuming that each tab click has its fragment, how can I make the last tab (say the 3rd tab) takes over the whole screen? I mean if someone clicks on the tab3 widget, instead of just display the content under the action bar, I want this fragment to be the full screen (expands over the action bar screen).

Please help me
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`getActionBar().hide()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#hide%28%29) (or `getSupportActionBar().hide()` if you are using the compability package) to hide the Action Bar. You should call this method when your 3rd tab is switched to.

Keep in mind that if you hide the Action Bar, you may hide all of your other navigation options, too. You may want to leave the user some way out.

Comment: Great suggestion, I want the back button to take the user to the 2nd tab. So I guess I can implement "OnBackPressed" to go to second tab. Correct?

Comment: @Snake Correct. Make sure to call `.show()` on the Action Bar as well. (You may want to call it whenever any tab is opened that *isn't* the 3rd, like... `if (tabNum == 3) { hide bar } else { show bar }`).

Comment: Ahhhh Ok great. Thank you for the answer. I will accept the answer (unless it fails on me tonight ;)